# Login and get page using ruby curb

Tags: ruby, curl

I am trying use curl to login and fetch a page using the following code:

```
login_url = "http://somewebsite.com/login/act_check_login.cfm"
login_str = "str_username=someone@somewhere.com&str_password=CJDZFM"
page_url = "http://getsomepage.com?int_document_section_id=432"
cookie_txt = "/var/spool/cookies/cookie.txt"
curl = Curl::Easy.new(login_url)
curl.follow_location = true
curl.enable_cookies = true
curl.verbose = true
curl.headers = {
         "User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0",
         "Accept" => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
         "Accept-Language" => "en-US,en;q=0.5",
         "Accept-Encoding" => "gzip, deflate",
         "Keep-Alive" => "300",
         "Connection" => "Keep-Alive",
         "Expect" => ""
 }
curl.cookiefile = cookie_txt
curl.cookiejar = cookie_txt
curl.http_post(login_url, login_str)
curl.url = page_url
curl.http_get
page = curl.body_str
puts "page is #{page}"
render :text => "<h1>Test Page</>#{page}"
```

This isn't working fetching the page.  An ideas what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try  [Use open-uri and](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html)

curl may be not work in ruby

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html